# Change color of a styled checked checkbox with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I've been stuck on this for a while. To explain very quickly, i have a table of different checkboxes. The user checks however many boxes and clicks continue. The same table shows up on another page/ The boxes that were checked are suppose to load by the click of a button.

My question is, how can I change the color of my styled checkboxes to another color by the click of a button.

**Update, I've added code, sorry for the confusion, first time using this**

```css
table.example1, table.example1 th, table.example1 td {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    max-width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-color: #3e618b;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="example1" id="example" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
              <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"value="2">
            <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<button>Changes checked checkbox color</button>
```

Comment: Show html of the checkboxes.

Comment: At the click of the button you can add with jquery to all selected checkboxes another class which you could customize (set the color you want) with css... If you want a working solution however you should provide your html.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please, add some code in your question. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to reproduce your issue of your code.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Not all browsers even support the styling of checkboxes or support styling to the same degree.

Comment: I've added code, thank you for the help

Comment: Why does your button say *"Changes radio button onclick"* when you aren't using radio buttons?

Comment: That button is just to show what I want the button to do. I could remove it for any confusion. But what I want the button to change the color of my style checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add a class to the label and then define the color based on that class like so:

```js
function toggle() {
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].classList.toggle('color');
  }
}
```

```css
table.example1,
table.example1 th,
table.example1 td {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  max-width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background-color: #3e618b;
  outline: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked+label.color {
  background-color: red;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="example1" id="example" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
      <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk" value="2">
      <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="toggle()">Changes radio button onclick</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change class attribute of a parent by click on the button.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table").toggleClass("alternative");
});
```

```css
table.example1, table.example1 th, table.example1 td {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    max-width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-color: #3e618b;
    outline: 0;
}
.alternative input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="example1" id="example" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
              <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"value="2">
            <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<button>Changes checked checkbox color</button>
```

Comment: I just add [descendant selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) to your CSS and button click event handler that toggle special class of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just CSS

HIDE THE ORIGINAL INPUT FIELD

```
input[type=checkbox]{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
```

Then add your own custom css to display the fields

```
input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
  height:18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:4px;
  width:18px;
}
```

Then add your css for your desired style and background when the checkbox is selected

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
      background: gold;
}
```

Comment: You used radio, can it be used with checkbox?

Comment: yes just change radio for checkbox:
and perhaps you might want to change border radius from 50% to something like 4px

Comment: I've changed it for you in my answer now:

You can do this because all you are doing is hidding the visibility of the original element, and then you just display something else with CSS and this can be anything you want even a picture as a background etc...